# finding the longest stretch of rows of data entries by grouping variable using tidyverse/ other R command

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse

I am not sure if I describe my question with the correct title but the idea is:

I would like to longest stretch of rows of data entries of each group after using `group_by()` which is also sensitive to the current order of rows. In other words, there are a (or multiple) discontinuities within a group (e.g. after `arrange()` by some other columns). I would like to get a new column (e.g. `mutate()`) that labels the rows that are within the longest stretch of each group. below is an example:

```
data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2),
           order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17))
```

In which, I would like to get a data frame like the following:

```
data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2),
           order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17),
           longest = c(T, T, T, F, F, T, T, T, T, T, F, F, F, F, T, T, T))
```

Comment: Rows 15-17 are a contiguous group of `id=2`, length 3, though the previous longest-run is in rows 6-10, length 5. Why is `longest` true for those last few rows?

Comment: @r2evans I would need the longest stretch for each group. Thus, the last three rows should be T for group 2 while the 4th and 5th row is F for group 2. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a group for the consecutive values in the `group` column. Then, get the number of rows for those groups, then we can group by `group` and return `TRUE` for the rows that have the greatest number of consecutive rows for each group.

```
library(tidyverse)
  
df %>% 
  group_by(group_weight = cumsum(c(1, diff(group) != 0))) %>% 
  mutate(longest = n()) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(longest = longest == max(longest)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-group_weight)
```

**Output**

```
   group order longest
   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
 1     1     1 TRUE   
 2     1     2 TRUE   
 3     1     3 TRUE   
 4     2     4 FALSE  
 5     2     5 FALSE  
 6     3     6 TRUE   
 7     3     7 TRUE   
 8     3     8 TRUE   
 9     3     9 TRUE   
10     3    10 TRUE   
11     1    11 FALSE  
12     1    12 FALSE  
13     3    13 FALSE  
14     1    14 FALSE  
15     2    15 TRUE   
16     2    16 TRUE   
17     2    17 TRUE
```

If you have a tie among consecutive rows and only want to return the first grouping as `T`, then you could do something like this:

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(group_weight = cumsum(c(1, diff(group) != 0))) %>% 
  mutate(longest = n()) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(longest = longest==max(longest)) %>% 
  group_by(longest, .add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(x = min(group_weight)) %>% 
  ungroup(longest) %>% 
  mutate(longest = longest == TRUE & group_weight == x & !is.na(x)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  dplyr::select(-c(group_weight, x))
```

*Output*

```
   group order longest
   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
 1     1     1 TRUE   
 2     1     2 TRUE   
 3     1     3 TRUE   
 4     2     4 FALSE  
 5     2     5 FALSE  
 6     3     6 TRUE   
 7     3     7 TRUE   
 8     3     8 TRUE   
 9     3     9 TRUE   
10     3    10 TRUE   
11     1    11 FALSE  
12     1    12 FALSE  
13     3    13 FALSE  
14     1    14 FALSE  
15     2    15 TRUE   
16     2    16 TRUE   
17     2    17 TRUE   
18     1    18 FALSE  
19     1    19 FALSE  
20     1    20 FALSE
```

*Data*

```
df2 <- structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 
3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: Why `ifelse(longest == max(longest), TRUE, FALSE)` and not just `longest == max(longest)`?

Comment: @r2evans Thank you! Just a bad habit I still need to break as I seem to default to `ifelse`.

Comment: If there is more than one consecutive stretch of the maximum length for a given group then they will both be marked as TRUE.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I didn't pick up that the OP needed to consider ties (but might be missing it). But I add an option for if they just want the first group with max length to  be TRUE instead of all that are max.

Answer (score 3):

in Base R:

```
df$longest <- with(rle(df$group), 
                    rep(ave(lengths, values, FUN = max) == lengths,lengths))

df
   group order longest
1      1     1    TRUE
2      1     2    TRUE
3      1     3    TRUE
4      2     4   FALSE
5      2     5   FALSE
6      3     6    TRUE
7      3     7    TRUE
8      3     8    TRUE
9      3     9    TRUE
10     3    10    TRUE
11     1    11   FALSE
12     1    12   FALSE
13     3    13   FALSE
14     1    14   FALSE
15     2    15    TRUE
16     2    16    TRUE
17     2    17    TRUE
```

Another Base R:

```
a <- rle(df$group)
a$values <- ave(a$lengths, a$values, FUN = max) == a$lengths

df$longest <- inverse.rle(a)
```

In data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, N := .N, by = rleid(group)][, longest := N == max(N), by = group][]

   group order N longest
 1:     1     1 3    TRUE
 2:     1     2 3    TRUE
 3:     1     3 3    TRUE
 4:     2     4 2   FALSE
 5:     2     5 2   FALSE
 6:     3     6 5    TRUE
 7:     3     7 5    TRUE
 8:     3     8 5    TRUE
 9:     3     9 5    TRUE
10:     3    10 5    TRUE
11:     1    11 2   FALSE
12:     1    12 2   FALSE
13:     3    13 1   FALSE
14:     1    14 1   FALSE
15:     2    15 3    TRUE
16:     2    16 3    TRUE
17:     2    17 3    TRUE
```